# 'float' object is not subscriptable during while loop

Tags: list, python-3.x, while-loop

The following code is part of a class, in which I am trying to calculate `self.rating`:

```
def calcrating(self):
    '''go through all sub-lists in info adding up totals for touchdowns, 
    attempts, etc. Then calculate the overall rating for this player. 
    Store it in the instance variable "rating".  
    If the player's total attempts is 0, set the rating to 0. '''

    count = 0
    touchdowns = 0
    attempts = 0
    yards = 0 
    fumbles = 0

    while count < len(self.info):
        touchdowns += int(self.info[count][5])
        attempts += int(self.info[count][3])
        yards += int(self.info[count][4])
        fumbles += int(self.info[count][6])
        count +=1
        if attempts == 0:
            self.rating =0
        else:
            yds = float(yards) / (4.05 * (attempts))
            if yds > 2.375:
                yds = 2.375            

            perTDs = (29.5 * (touchdowns))/ (attempts)
            if perTDs >2.375:
                perTDs = 2.375

            perFumbles = 2.375 - ((21.5* (fumbles))/ \
                                   (attempts))

            self.rating = (yds + perTDs + perFumbles) * (100/4.5)                
    count = 0                    
    return self.rating
```

`self.info` is a list of lists, and I am trying to comb through the 5th index of each list and I go though it.  If I change the `self.info[count][5]` to `self.info[0][5]`, it will work, but clearly won't go through the rest of the lists.

Any ideas on why this is? Is it because I made `self.info[count][5]` an int during the first time through the while loop?

Comment: so what is the problem/error?